# Using a Generic IValueConverter from XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a generic class implementing `IValueConverter`. Something like:

```
class MyValueConverter<T> : IValueConverter
```

With XAML 2009, I can use it like this:

```
<my:MyValueConverter x:TypeArguments='x:String'/>
```

But apparently that's not allowed for "compiled" XAML (I guess we'll have to wait for .NET 5)

My current workaround is subclassing it for each usage:

```
class FooMyValueConverter : MyValueConverter<Foo>
```

Is it possible to do this in markup only using XAML 2006?

Comment: Were you getting **error MC6022** there by any chance? (Trying to find out whether I am having the same problem, or whether I should create a new question.)

Comment: @o.r.mapper, this was 4 years and 2 technology stacks ago; I really don't remember.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could probably do this with a custom [MarkupExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747254.aspx)([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150528010306/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747254.aspx))([v4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms747254(v=vs.100).aspx)). Something like:

```
public class MyMarkupExtension : MarkupExtension {

    public MyMarkupExtension() {
        this.Type = /* some default type */;
    }

    public MyMarkupExtension(Type type) {
        this.Type = type;
    }

    public Type Type { get; private set; }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) {
        Type type = typeof(MyValueConverter<>).MakeGenericType(this.Type);
        return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    }
}
```

Then you'd use it like `{Binding ... Converter={local:MyMarkup {x:Type BounceEase}}}`

Comment: Great idea. I'll just make it generic so I can instantiate any generic type.