# Is it possible to create generic ValidationRule classes?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, validation

I am working on a .NET 4.0 project that deals with validation of the range of a particular data type. For example, a 32 bit int should only be between `Int32.MinValue` and `Int32.MaxValue` or any other value defined by the application. I want to be able to specify data types and ranges on a custom validator so they can be called directly from the xaml through binding: `<CheckIfValueRangeValidator>`

This is what I have in mind, I am not sure it will work or if it can even be done through the xaml.

```
class CheckIfValueInRangeValidator<T> : ValidationRule
{
    public T Max { get; set; }
    public T Min { get; set; }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        // Implementation...
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use x:Type in XAML to specify the type you are passing to your rule.

Comment: Could you answer this by showing an example Validation Rule class and an XAML call example?

Comment: Just how would you assign a value of less than Int32.MinValue to an Int32?  How do you expect to set the "value" outside the range of Int32 in the "set"?

Comment: @Blam that is just an example. Ideally the user of this class can specify any range he/she wants, not just those.

Comment: @Blam This should easily work for any data type.

Comment: And just how are you going to determine if T is GT max.  Object does not even have a GT or LT comparitors.

Comment: @Blam The use cases would be limited to objects that in their hierarchical inheritance implement comparitors (ints, floats, etc)

Comment: Would be limited - How?  You are using T with validate object.

Comment: It can still be done, but it would not be safe since this validator is only used internally.

Comment: Then please post the code for how you expect to perform this unsafe comparison.

Comment: @Blam I believe that is slightly off the scope of my question. I just want to know if it is possible to call and assign types to generic validators in the ValidationRules binding.

Comment: How is that out of scope of the question?  You post this is what I have in mind.  I point out what you have in mind won't work and why.  You state it will work.   I ask you so show how.  And your answer is that is off scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad, actually you cannot use x:TypeArguments as it will raise *x:TypeArguments is not allowed in object elements for XAML version lower than 2009*, it's valid only on loose XAML files or the root element (Window in my case) ...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750476.aspx

But as a workaround you could use the following pattern :

```xml
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox1">
        <Binding Path="MyValue"
                     Source="{StaticResource MyObject}"
                     UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <wpfApplication6:MyValidationRule ObjectType="{x:Type system:Int32}"   />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox>
```

Code behind :

```cs
public class MyObject
{
    public object MyValue { get; set; }
}

public class MyValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public Type ObjectType { get; set; }

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Take a look at this one too : 
[Using a Generic IValueConverter from XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833143/using-a-generic-ivalueconverter-from-xaml)

@Blam comment is worthwhile to consider, a range to check generally applies for an integer or a double, for other types I'd say you could just add a boolean that return the validity of that object and perform such validation inside the object itself.

For numbers you have [RangeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but it's not really part of the WPF validation infrastructure.

You also have an another option for validation : [INotifyDataErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) validation takes place inside the object in this case.

I wrote a lengthy answer here : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/203590/is-there-an-effective-way-for-creating-complex-forms you might find something useful on it.

From my experience I'd say that a generic validating rule is probably not wise to do.

You should edit your question to be less *generic* ;-) but rather more specific, you'd get more help from people here. Give one or two concrete cases of the objects you are trying to validate.

**EDIT**

You can also use a BindingGroup for validating an object :

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TextBox1_OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        grid.BindingGroup.CommitEdit();
    }
}

public class Indices
{
    public int ColorIndex { get; set; }
    public string ColorPrefix { get; set; }
    public int GradientIndex { get; set; }
    public string GradientPrefix { get; set; }
}

public class ValidateMe : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var bindingGroup = value as BindingGroup;
        var o = bindingGroup.Items[0] as Indices;
        return new ValidationResult(true, null);
    }
}
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpfApplication6="clr-namespace:WpfApplication6"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="525"
        Height="350">
    <Window.Resources>
        <wpfApplication6:Indices x:Key="Indices"
                                 ColorIndex="1"
                                 ColorPrefix="MyColor"
                                 GradientIndex="1"
                                 GradientPrefix="MyGradient" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid x:Name="grid" DataContext="{StaticResource Indices}">
        <Grid.BindingGroup>
            <BindingGroup>
                <BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
                    <wpfApplication6:ValidateMe />
                </BindingGroup.ValidationRules>
            </BindingGroup>
        </Grid.BindingGroup>
        <TextBox TextChanged="TextBox1_OnTextChanged">
            <Binding Path="ColorIndex" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Using RangeAtribute :

```cs
    private void test()
    {
        Indices indices = new Indices();
        indices.ColorIndex = 20;

        var validationContext = new ValidationContext(indices);
        var validationResults = new List<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult>();
        var tryValidateObject = Validator.TryValidateObject(indices, validationContext, validationResults,true);
    }

public class Indices
{
    [Range(1, 10)]
    public int ColorIndex { get; set; }

    public string ColorPrefix { get; set; }
    public int GradientIndex { get; set; }
    public string GradientPrefix { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: I needed a `ValidationRule` specific to the binding source, i.e. I wanted the source to define the rule.

I ended up using the following approach of an attached property that sets the binding incl. rule via code.

**ICustomRuleProvider.cs**: Interface the binding source (ViewModel) must implement.

```
public interface ICustomRuleProvider
{
    ValidationRule CreateRule();
}
```

**CustomRule.cs**: Attached property used in Xaml to create the required binding incl. rule.

```
public class CustomRule
{
    public static ICustomRuleProvider GetProvider(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ICustomRuleProvider)obj.GetValue(ProviderProperty);
    }

    public static void SetProvider(DependencyObject obj, ICustomRuleProvider value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ProviderProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ProviderProperty =

        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Provider", typeof(ICustomRuleProvider), typeof(CustomRule), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, CustomRule.OnProviderPropertyChanged));

    public static void OnProviderPropertyChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(sender is TextBox fe)) return;

        var provider = e.NewValue as ICustomRuleProvider;

        if (provider != null)
        {
            var b = new Binding("Value");
            b.ValidationRules.Add(provider.CreateRule());

            fe.SetBinding(System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.TextProperty, b);
        }
        else
        {
            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(fe, TextBox.TextProperty);
        }
    }
}
```

**Example:** Be sure to define `xmlns:customRule="clr-namespace:...;assembly=..."`

```
<TextBox customRule:CustomRule.Provider="{Binding}"/>
```

This implementation is tailor-made for binding a the `Text` property of a `TextBox` the "Value" property of the binding source, but this can easily be extended.

Using this I was able to use a custom (generic) converter.

BTW: I do not agree that a custom generic `ValidationRule` is a "bad idea", although the use cases may be limited. In many cases it may be necessary to also implement a custom `IValueConverter` and assign that to the binding as well to have full control over the object value on its way from the control to the source.